# Add a new column next to a container div in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, and although my layout is very simple, there is a thing I cannot achieve.

I would like to add a new column next to a container div.

[image: This is what I have at the moment]

All I want is to keep the "container" layout and attach a "category" box at his left. Right now is too far away depending of the screen size.

This is the code right now:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:cyan;">Categories</div>
      <div class="container" style="background-color:orange;">Container</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update 1:
[image]

Update 2:

```
     <!-- Example -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey;">
    Level 1: .col-sm-12 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" style="background-color:orange;">
        Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="container" style="background-color:red;">
        Level 2: container
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can't add column next to the container. You have to set `position` `absolute/fixed` to your categories sidebar to achieve your goal.

Comment: I think I got it! can you see the example?

Comment: Read Bootstrap documentation about grid. You can't nest `container` in `container-fluid`. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yeah I know but is what I want

Comment: It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">left side content</div>
<div class="col-md-8">middle content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">right side content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Don't add container inside container-fluid, because container element has fix width, and your layout is fluid.
Read bootstrap documentation carefully :)

Comment: The whole website has a fix width (using container class) and that the reason I had to do this trick, to put outside in the most responsive way a sidebar. In that way you put it does not match with my layout, because any grid does not march with the size of the container. I do not know if I explain it well, anyway I think it works now

Comment: Maybe another way is to change the size of the grid to make it match with the container class...